# c++ can't find max in string. I always got number 49, 51, 53, 54

Tags: c++, max

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string str;

int max();

int main()
{
    cout << " your number: ";
    cin >> str;
    cout << endl << endl;

    if( str.size() > 10 )
    {
        cout << " number cant be bigger than 10";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << max();
    }   

    return 0;
}

int max() {
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if( str[i] > max )
            max = str[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: And your question is? Also, do you know what ASCII is?

Comment: Characters are actually integer numbers. Checkout the ASCII table.

Comment: `int max() {
    int max = 0;` and `#include<bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std`, Try to have name conflicts? (missing `#include <windows.h>` for the MACRO ^^)

Comment: Don't input numbers as strings, unless you are manipulating digits.  Change your `str` variable to an integer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Or validating input. But I'd use `std::getline` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change return type of `int max()` function to `char max()`.

Or

Print type converted return value of max like below

```
cout << static_cast<char>(max());
```

Or

Change ASCII number to a integer by subtracting `'0'` like below

```
cout << max() - '0';
```

Or

Print return value as char with c style printf like below

```
printf("%c", max());
```

Comment: Highly recommend changing the C-style cast to `static_cast`.

Comment: both of these work

Comment: @sweenish thanks to point out. I modified the content.